# Dynamically Provide Username and password to Connection String

Tags: c#, mysql, connection

I am using C# winform application using MySql as back-end database. Using App.config file, application read connection string to connect database as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
   <connectionstring>
  <addkey="MySQL.DB"value="server=localhost;database=mysqldbname;user=username;password=12345678;">
   </add>
 </connectionstring>
 </configuration>
```

Is there any way that we can provide username and password not from App.config but from user of application, by entering username and password? so that we are able to protect sensitive data. Other information are ok to read from app.config like database name, server etc.

Ahmed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can have `appSettings`

```
   <appSettings>
        <add key="ConFormat" value="server=localhost;database=mysqldbname;user={0};password={1};"/>
    </appSettings>
```

read it and set the values

```
var formatString  = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConFormat"].ToString();
var conString  = string.Format(formatString , SecureUserName, SecurePW);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using raw ADO.NET then you can use a connection string builder, presumably a MySqlConnectionStringBuilder in your case.  Create a new instance with the connection string from the config file, set the appropriate properties and then get the result from the ConnectionString property.

By the way, you can store passwords and other sensitive data in the config file using Protected Configuration to encrypt it.

Comment: @jmcilhinnet it's a very good suggestion, but Damith has provide more better solution with example.

Comment: No, Damith has provided an inferior solution with an example.  If you want to use that because you can copy and paste the example and not have to think for yourself then that's up to you.

Comment: Actually no...it's more then just copy/paste...I've to do far more changes in connection..obviously when a newbie post a problem, it's only a symptoms and not the whole project here. Damith's solution provide a clear path to implement in my project.

Comment: Are you saying that my solution doesn't provide a clear path to implementation in your project?  I told you exactly what to do.  You simply have to follow those very simple instructions.  Also, it's the way you're supposed to do it.  Using a connection string builder, there's no need to add dummy values or place-holders if you don't already have the data but you can also provide default values if appropriate.  If you don't want to do it the proper way then that's up to you.

Comment: I am saying that Damith's solution provide **more** clear path to solution of my problem. Anyone who is looking for answer for this type of problem will clearly go for Damith's approach.

Comment: Then they'd be taking the inferior option.  If you want to take the inferior option, that's your prerogative.  Perhaps you're just unable to follow the simple instructions I provided and others will be able to implement the superior solution.

Comment: Well that's depend upon what other thinks about whose solution is inferior or superior...In my opinion Damith's solution is superior then yours. I've use raw ADO.NET and I can surely follow your simple instructions, but I find Damith's more simple and superior. So instead of misjudging me, kindly accept it.

Comment: Well the purpose of this forum is share knowledge, and not to be egoistic....so get over it...

Comment: I'm not being egotistical.  I didn't say that I'm better than Damith or you for that matter.  I just know enough about .NET programming to know the difference between the two proposed solutions and therefore to know which is better than the other.  I'm sharing that knowledge with you but you refuse to take notice.

Comment: Oh I did take notice, but upon comparison I find Damith's approach more better then yours. If you don't want to accept the fact that's up to you, me or any other member cannot force you to do that.

Comment: I have accepted that you have made the wrong decision.

Comment: Restricted to what exactly?  If you're so confident that you made the right decision, why do you care?  I've been doing this long enough to know what's the better option here.  I think that if there's an ego at play here it's yours.  As I've said, it's your prerogative to go whichever way you want here.  I know which is the better option as a result of my 11 years of .NET experience, additional years of commercial programming experience and Computer Science degree.  You are free to think that you know better.

Comment: Yes I am confident with my decision...I care becoz you are trying to de-grade other member, you just can't accept the fact that someone might gave better solution...and if you are confident about your solution, why bother trying so hard to prove it...let other members decide to do that...as far as I am concern I am far from being egoistic, I post my problem and found best solution so I accept the answer....you just can't accept that you are wrong...I am sure your ego will again push you to reply.

Comment: I'm not trying to degrade anyone.  I haven't said anything about any other member.  I'm more than happy for someone else to provide a better solution than I do if one exists.  As for the solution in this case, if you're happy to use other than what I suggested then that's your prerogative but it is not a better solution and your insisting that it is doesn't make it so.  You can use whatever solution you want but the best solution is the best solution, whether you use it or not.  I'm sure that your ego will again cause you to question my ego.

Comment: Like you said **the best solution is the best**.....this isn't a professional attitude holding 11 years experience...in my opinion it's a childish stubborn...  and like you copy my quote **I am sure that your ego will again cause you to reply**

Comment: oh and a person having 11 years experience showing such a childish attitude means either he/she is not a professional or he/she has some kind of ego problem..And because I am not a professional so I can debate it forever....

Comment: Oh, that's clever: if I reply then it's because I have an ego problem and if I don't then you "win"?  The simple fact is that there were two possible solutions on the table and you chose the inferior of the two.  That's your prerogative.  Now you're stuck with it.  My congratulations.  I won't be commenting again whether my ego tells me to or not.  If you feel the need to have the last word then you may do so, if you find that comforting.  It still doesn't change anything, for you or for me.  Have a good life.

Comment: Well that's your opinion and no body here needs to agree with it.. So if you think your solution is superior and every other is always a *Second*, then problem is clearly at your end..and like you said it still doesn't change anything or doesn't change the fact actually..And also there is no *winning* or loosing here...this discussion got lengthy only because you are unwilling to accept that there are more better experience people in this forum..Have a good life to you too..and hope to see you participate in my future posts..

Answer (score 0):

Change the code in app.config like this

```
<add key="MySQL.DB"value="server=localhost;database=mysqldbname;user=&usernamefromuser;password=&passfromuser;">
```

Add a button for connecting and 2 textboxes for username and password

Buttons code :

```
//other code for mysql variables ...
string connectionStr= connStrFrom_App_Config.Replace("&usernamefromuser",texBox1.Text).Replace("&passfromuser",textBox2.Text);
//other code for connecting
```